# Indirect indexed on X register - Assembler 6502

Tags: assembly, 6502

So I'm trying to figure out how to bypass the fact that LDX doesn't have an option for indirect indexed, but I'm all out of luck. (Pretty new with assembler)
I'm using LDA (arrPoint), Y to load an get an MSB from the int array and I want to use LDX (arrPoint), Y to get the LSB.

Any tips on how I can write this so I can use indirect indexed with the X register ?

Here's some of my code, where arrPoint is located at memory $1000, and slask is 2 databytes.

```
getInt: 
    ASL
    STA $36
    LDY $36
    LDX arrPoint, Y
    INY
    LDA (arrPoint), Y

    RTS

setInt:
    STY slask
    ASL slask
    LDY slask
    STX arrPoint, Y
    INY
    STA (arrPoint), Y

    RTS
```

Thanks

Comment: If you don't mind trashing the `A` register you can use the undocumented instruction `LAX (arrPoint),Y` (loads the same value in to both `A` and `X`). The opcode is `$B3` in case your assembler doesn't support undocumented instructions.

Comment: Well it's seems like I couldn't use LAX, but couldn't I possible first load one byte into the Accumilator and then write TAX to transfer it to the X register then just load the second byte into the Accumilator ?

Comment: `LAX` is 1 byte and 1 cycle less than `LDA` + `TAX` if I'm counting correctly. But other than that it would be the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider transforming the array to

```
 uint8_t lsb[N];
 uint8_t msb[N];
```

allowing

```
LDA lsb, Y
TAX                ;; faster alternative to STA $36 + LDX $36
LDA msb, Y
RTS
```

Answer (score 2):

As described by Michael in the OP comments, LAX is a good solution here provided you:

1. Are writing for the original NMOS 6502,
2. Have no philosophical objection to using undocumented opcodes, and
3. Don't need to preserve (or have otherwise safeguarded) the Accumulator (.A) contents

LAX loads both .A and .X with the value from a memory location, *or with the immediate value zero* (see below). Addressing modes:

```
Mnemonic    Bytes       Cycles
LAX #00     AB 00       2
LAX abcd    AF cd ab    4
LAX abcd,Y  BF cd ab    4 (+1 if crossing page boundary)
LAX ab      A7 ab       3
LAX ab,Y    B7 ab       4
LAX (ab,X)  A3 ab       6
LAX (ab),Y  B3 ab       5 (+1 if crossing page boundary)
```

LAX is documented as lacking the immediate addressing mode (`LAX #nn`) but in fact `LAX #$00` is stable and useful when you want to set both .A and .X to zero - it takes 2 bytes and 2 cycles instead of 4 of each (`LDA #$00; LDX #$00`) or 3 bytes / 4 cycles (`LDA #$00; TAX`).

This DASM macro injects the byte sequence in response to a custom mnemonic (`ZAX`, Zero .A and .X):

```
  MAC ZAX
    DC.W #$00AB ; [2] LAX Immediate Zero (only stable when operand is zero)
  ENDM
```

This is a short excerpt from a text bitmap rendering routine I wrote which uses LAX to index into a byte-pair address table:

```
.dodraw LAX (_TEXTADDR),Y   ; [5] get first character of pair from text-buffer
        LDA _CHARTABL,X     ; [4] get first glyph data address lo-byte
        STA _GLYPADD1       ; [3] ZP set first glyph data address lo-byte
        LDA _CHARTABH,X     ; [4] get first glyph data address hi-byte
        STA _GLYPADD1+1     ; [3] ZP set first glyph data address hi-byte
        etc...
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this code won't function on a 65c02 or newer.

Comment: That was literally my first point.